# Create SOAP file help

Tags: asp.net, xml, soap

How to create SOAP 1.1 file?

Is it xml file, or?
[This is the file](https://webservices.nbs.rs/CommunicationOfficeService1_0/ExchangeRateService.asmx?op=GetExchangeRateByDate) that I need to make.

When I copie theat cod in xml, an error occurs:**XML Parsing Error: syntax error
POST /CommunicationOfficeService1_0/ExchangeRateXmlService.asmx HTTP/1.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What toolset are you using to call this web service? I am going to assume that you haven't worked with "web services" before.

Instead of creating the XML by hand I would recommend using .net or java to create "proxy" class code against this "WSDL". You can start by googling or binging for "How to consume a web service in .net" or your language of choice.

I reserve the right to change my answer as additional details emerge.

Comment: I know just PHP, HTML, XML, CSS. Web services is something new for me. I'll try to find "HOW TO" on google.